# PowerPivot Data Refresh Exception

Tags: powerpivot

I am trying to resolve the following Error in my ULS logs.  I have a ticket open with Microsoft and even they cannot get it resolved yet so I thought I would post it here.  These errors come in pairs with the same CorrellationID.

```
 EXCEPTION: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration.DataRefreshException: 
The application has detected that another process is attempting a malicious action 
on the shared synchronization object object. The application will close immediately.
at Nicrosoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration.GeminiDataRefreshTimerJob.CheckOwnerAgainstWSSWPG(ObjectSecurity objSecurity)

    Product: SSAS Mid-Tier Service
    Category: Data Refresh
    Process: w3wp.exe
    EventID: 99
```

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? I have the same issue now (12/5/2011). Anyone have the resolution?

Comment: Not yet.  I believe MS has found the issue and will be providing me a work-around.  I'll update soon.

Comment: curious, what did MS tell you?

Comment: I am also running into this exception. Did anyone find a solution, for sp2010 with sql2008r2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was resolved but on my side, I fixed those issue by registering a DLL for SQL Analysis Services OLE DB Provider on the server where excel services is running. You can find the reference there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210608.aspx

Here are the important steps:

1.Use the regasm.exe utility to register the file. If you have not run regasm.exe before, add its parent folder, :\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\, to the system path variable.

2.Open a command prompt with administrator permissions.

3.Go to this folder :\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ChannelTransport\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91 (it's 10 instead of 11 if it is SQL 2008 R2 component).

4.Enter the following command: regasm microsoft.analysisservices.channeltransport.dll

5.Repeat the previous steps for any computer on which you manually installed the 2008 R2 version of the provider.